# Developer Accounts for ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, developer-edition

Has there been any progress made on granting a developer account for SF and HubExchange Devs?
It feels conceptually wrong to me a SF product doesn't allow developers to perfect and develop a wider solution offering without paying +10K license fee per year. Even without CRM the HubExchange market could be a richer portal for consumers and developers if we were allowed a means to test our concept.

I think we'd all be perfectly happy with an account that was blackholed or limited in such a way where we could only send a finite qty of emails to an email address associated to the user.

If there's a forum or avenue where we can assist in raising the value proposition please let us know as I know there are many people looking.

Comment: Let me come up with something for this. Thanks for this!

Comment: See if you can get your network to sign the petition. The quicker we can sign it, the more meansjg it will have.

Comment: I've posted internally at Slalom's CRM practice as well as a few other locales. Hoping to see this go!

Comment: I have confirmed with my account manager that ExactTarget aren't running trial licenses anymore, and haven't for quite some time. This isn't something that is being offered and it isn't something that looks likely to be offered in the near future either. One can request a demo though via https://www.exacttarget.com/uk/request-a-demo

Comment: Any updates on a dev account for SFMC?

Answer (score 15):

I created a petition at iPetitions and I'm looking for 2500 developer signatures asking for this.  You can locate the petitions here - http://www.ipetitions.com/petition/exacttarget-developer-edition

Feel free to spread the word.

Comment: Lets make it happen!

Answer (score 7):

Check out the Marketing Cloud Developer Edition here, it was announced at Connections 2014 in late September:

https://code.exacttarget.com/developer-edition/

Comment: I created an account earlier in October for this and it was working, just checked it again and it seems to be down... is the developer edition gone?

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I noticed the site is down today. Hoping it comes back online soon

Comment: I've tried a few times today and it appears to be down, I noticed the one account i didn't activate is dead. Might be an indication to a change.

Comment: The dev edition is currently offline - but should be up again soon.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews: Still offline.  What are we supposed to do to test app install procedures without an account?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews any update, please? I checked this link here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000Zho3AAC and seems that developer editions are paid for (USD 10k p/a) or not available at all. It's quite confusing.

Comment: I don't work for Salesforce any longer. I'm afraid I'm not much help.

Answer (score 3):

This has been dormant for a while but for anyone looking for this in 2017...

It's still not available. However if you work for a Salesforce Partner, you can have one provisioned . This version doesnt come with a functional mobile connect as there is an actual cost to it. If a partner really wants this, there is an option to pay for this at a discounted rate.

I would like to see a new petition started as the unavailability of this greatly limits the growth of the marketing cloud ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

There is an idea shared on the SF Help page:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ

It has a score of over 4K and shows that it is PRODUCT TEAM REVIEW and that we should have an update in the next 2-4 months

If you are still interested in this, I recommend going in and upvoting the idea.  More votes may help get this ball rolling a little faster.

Answer (score 3):

Still no developer instance and 5 years later. I don’t think it’s ever happening for the general public similar to what Salesforce CRM has available as a [Developer Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup)

*But* if you are a Salesforce Partner, you can request a free Marketing Cloud developer account. This can be requested by creating a case on the [Partner Portal](https://partners.salesforce.com/).

[Salesforce Partner Program](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Program) supports AppExchange (ISV) Partners, Consulting Partners, and Resellers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/107330)

Comment: The answer is “I don’t think it’s ever happening.”