# Which Salesforce Edition should I sign up for to learn how it works?

Tags: editions, pricing

For a new user, there's a lot of options in signing up for a Salesforce edition.

But if I wanted to sign up to learn how to use the platform, what would be the most appropriate edition to use?

Ideally I'm looking for something quite cheap or even free, but I do realise that Salesforce's pricing structure might not make that too easy! This will just be me using it at the moment to learn, so I'm not concerned about user limits or even limits on most other things in the system.

I came across a 'personal edition' online which sounds like it could be perfect, but I apparently it has been discontinued - and indeed I can't find a way to signup for it.

Is there any other option available short of the 30-day free trial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the below link to learn. Below is the developer org and you can access every new feature...

https://developer.salesforce.com/signup

Also refer TrailHead and complete all the courses. Use the same signup credentials

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en

Comment: The Developer Org is pretty fully featured - to an equivalent of the Performance Edition in some areas, except for being limited to 2 active user accounts. If you start learning with Trailhead which is an excellent resource some modules require you to sign up for a special DE org such as Wave Analytics with some specific additional features.

Answer (score 5):

For your use case you need Developer Edition. Just go to [Developer edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) and signup for a free account.

Also take a look at [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/modules) and some developer module which help you get started.

Answer (score 3):

Sign up for a free developer org

https://developer.salesforce.com/signup

Developer Edition (often referred to as a "DE org") is a fully-featured development environment with limits on data and users.

When you're ready to begin developing, you'll find that Developer Edition is equipped the full Salesforce CRM suite, along with all the latest developer technologies. Sign up for a Developer Edition and you'll get your new environment provisioned immediately. Note that Developer Edition orgs continue to be available as long as they have some type of activity within the previous six months.

Comment: Also, the data limit for DE orgs is 5GB and the # of users is limited to 2. Idea to increase data limit can be found here, to vote on: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpkIAAS

Comment: @AndyHitchings The DE limits actually have been increased. My primary DE org has 20MB/1GB of storage.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Mine has 5MB still...I will create a new DE. Thanks!

Comment: Mine has 20MB data storage / 20MB file storage

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the Developer Org, there is also a [Training Org](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial_training.jsp), which may be helpful when learning Salesforce alongside (typically paid-for) training course(s). As per the link:

> Taking an online course and need a training lab? Sign up for the
>   training environment today and receive access to a preconfigured
>   salesforce.com org for 30 days. Refer to your exercise guide (found in
>   the online course attachments) for details about which training lab
>   you need.

The Training Courses are typically used alongside Premier Support Help & Training courses.

Note: there is currently no Developer or Training org available for the Salesforce Marketing Cloud. More info can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34198/developer-accounts-for-exacttarget).